# Listen for 'paid for full version' event in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an Chrome Extension uploaded in Chrome Store, it has free trial and paid modes (only One Time payment is available for paid modes)

I need to be able to recognize when user switches between these modes from extension's background script, so I can enable\disable premium functionality.

Official docs don't contain anything regarding this.

I tried adding `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` event listener, but it doesn't get triggered when user switches to paid mode...

I'm able to get current license version by hitting `https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/`
 but I don't think it's a best way to hit it each few seconds to check for license change, there must be a better way...

Comment: You can ask for a feature request regarding this on this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) and [the chromium tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: Did so, but I thought that someone else encountered the same issue before.